# c# foreach to loop through all dates between two datepickers

Tags: c#

I have two datepickers

```
string dateFIRST = (dateSTART.Value.ToString("yyMMdd"));
string dateLAST = (dateEND.Value.ToString("yyMMdd"));
```

How can I use a foreach loop to iterate through all dates using the "yymmdd" format? Also,  Can we possibly store the "yyMMdd" into an array since it will change each time during the foreach loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters, you need to get the dates in `DateTime` format, not as strings.

```
for (DateTime d = dateSTART.Value; d <= dateEND.Value; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    // d contains the date for this iteration
}
```

Comment: for my project purposes, I need the date variable to be in "yyMMdd" format

Comment: @SlopTonio Format the end results, not the dates themselves

Comment: Then convert to that format inside the loop. A string is not a good or efficient format to use for the loop itself.

Comment: oh I see, and how could I perform the conversion from d to "yymmdd"?

Comment: @SlopTonio: Just exactly as you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for (DateTime d = dateSTART.Value; d <= dateEND.Value; d = d.AddDays(1))
        {
            result.Add(d.ToString("yyMMdd"));
        }
```